# gcp datacatalog_v1beta1 create taxonomy and policy tags failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-data-api

I am trying to use Python Client for Google Cloud Data Catalog API beta 1 to create taxonomy and policy tags. here is my code:

```
from google.cloud.datacatalog_v1beta1 import PolicyTagManagerClient, enums, types
from google.oauth2 import service_account


key_path = "./xxxxx.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = PolicyTagManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
resource_name = '//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/{}/locations/us/taxonomies/{}'.format('3xxxxxxxx58','50xxxxxxxxx14')
taxonomy = client.get_taxonomy(resource_name) 
print(taxonomy)

pt_taxonomy = types.Taxonomy()
pt_taxonomy.display_name = 'PHI'
response = client.create_taxonomy(parent=<project_id>, taxonomy=pt_taxonomy)
```

I get following error for get_taxonomy()

```
google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled.
```

and for create_taxonomy() I got:

```
"Received http2 header with status: 404","grpc_status":1,"value":"404"}"
```

any idea? 
Thank you for your help!

BTW google api call does work, it returns 200 with following example.

[image]

So I changed my code to:

```
pt_taxonomy1 = types.Taxonomy()
pt_taxonomy1.display_name = 'PHI1'

response = client.create_taxonomy('projects/39xxxxx/locations/us', pt_taxonomy1)
```

still same 501 error

Answer (score 1):

@hdu, I filed a bug describing the `501` error in the client library repository: https://github.com/googleapis/python-datacatalog/issues/33.
[EDITED] This bug has been fixed.

In spite of the `501` error, I believe there's another minor issue in your script:

> resource_name = '//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/{}/locations/us/taxonomies/{}'.format('3xxxxxxxx58','50xxxxxxxxx14')
> taxonomy = client.get_taxonomy(resource_name)

**GET Taxonomy** expects the resource name of the requested taxonomy as an argument, formatted as `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}/taxonomies/{taxonomies_id}` ([source](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.taxonomies/get)).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [click here](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/core_errors#NOT_IMPLEMENTED), noticed that the error message NOT_IMPLEMENTED (501) has been described here. I guess you need to use parameters on  client.get_taxonomy() like project_id, region and cluster as resources have these parameters. You can look in to the article [click here](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.datacatalog.v1beta1#google.cloud.datacatalog.v1beta1.PolicyTagManager.CreateTaxonomy) for authorization scope and also [click here](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.taxonomies/create) for API method.